# Azure DevOps -> Pipelines -> Releases -> Access Azure Key Vault Secret -> nested levels JSON variable substitution/transform

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

I have an `appsettings.json` file where I want to transform the value located at:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
},
```

I found the following answer so I know that an app service can retrieve values directly from the key vault:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59994040/3850405

This is not the reason for asking. Since Microsoft offers `JSON variable substitution` I still think this should be possible since the only problem is the nested value. The question above is similar but I would like to specify a bit more what has already been tested and where I got stuck.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#json-variable-substitution

It is possible to use Pipelines -> Library -> Variable group

[image]

or a  Azure Key Vault Task to get the secret value.

[image]

The problem is the secret value can not contain dots:

[image]

> Please provide a valid secret name. Secret names can only contain
>   alphanumeric characters and dashes.

Neither in a linked Variable group or in a Azure Key Vault Task I'm allowed to rewrite a secret name to another variable name.

Looking at the sample below if the secret name was `ConnectionStringsDefaultConnection` I could access the value like this `$(ConnectionStringsDefaultConnection)` but I don't know how to rename it.

https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/azurekeyvault/

I have found a task that could get the job done but it requires a third party Release task. This is not acceptable since the project only allows Tasks written by Microsoft.

[image]

https://daniel-krzyczkowski.github.io/How-to-inject-Azure-Key-Vault-secrets-in-the-Azure-DevOps-CICD-pipelines/

I also know that a Pipeline variable can be used to store the value but we wan't to have a single source of truth and that is the Azure Key Vault Secret.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read a similar question from VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services) and was able to solve it.

Created a `Pipeline variable` called `ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection` that had a reference value to my linked variable group.

If my secret was named `ConnectionStringsDefaultConnection` I would hook this up as a linked variable and then add `$(ConnectionStringsDefaultConnection)` as a value.

[image]

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47787972/3850405

Answer (score 4):

I managed to resolve this issue automatically without the need to manage all the variables by myself.

I used the idea of @Ogglas and made this little script in an Azure Powershell task.

```
$results = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $(key-vault-name)

foreach ($result in $results)
{
    if ($result.Name.Contains("--")) {

        $key = $result.Name.Replace('--', '.')
        $value = '$(' + $result.Name.ToString() + ')'

        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$key;issecret=true;]$value"
    }
}
```

The "[Get-AzKeyVaultSecret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/get-azkeyvaultsecret?view=azps-8.3.0#example-1-get-all-current-versions-of-all-secrets-in-a-key-vault)" allow you to list all the variables present in your KeyVault and the "[Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell)" allow you to create variable that can be used in future tasks.

Like that, you can keep the KeyVault naming convention for the secrets, retrieves them in your pipeline and uses the task "[FileTransform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/file-transform-v2?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops)" from Microsoft to replace the values

See the example in a release:
[image: See the example in a release]

Answer (score 1):

One of the option will be to use Key Vault directly in your application instead of replacing your appsettings.json. You can configure this in `CreateHostBuilder` method:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
        {
            if (context.HostingEnvironment.IsProduction())
            {
                var builtConfig = config.Build();

                using (var store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
                {
                    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                    var certs = store.Certificates
                        .Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                            builtConfig["AzureADCertThumbprint"], false);

                    config.AddAzureKeyVault(
                        $"https://{builtConfig["KeyVaultName"]}.vault.azure.net/",
                        builtConfig["AzureADApplicationId"],
                        certs.OfType<X509Certificate2>().Single());

                    store.Close();
                }
            }
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

Please check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1).